# Maximum sum of values in matrix. Every column and row can only be used once

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, knapsack-problem

I want to find a combination of matrix entries that is a maximum. The constraints are that each row and column can only be used once but every row must be used once.

For example:

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 5 1
1 2 4 6
```

In this case the maximum combination would be (0,1) + (1,2) + (2,3) = 13

Obviously this small example can be brute-forced quite easily, but for example 40x50 matrices already are a problem. I think the brute force approach has factorial complexity and I want to get this down. Is there a good way to do that?
I have already looked at the knapsack problem and it seems quite similar but I still don't really get it.
I would implement the method in Python but just an approach or pseudo-code would already help a lot.

Comment: @mcsoini Yes, I meant row and column. I edited the question. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: The maximum should be 13 == 2 + 5 + 6?

Comment: Maybe this can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918741/

Comment: @DanielHao This is exactly what I need. Thanks and sorry for making a duplicate, I could not find it

Comment: Glad that it can help. Good Luck.  *maybe post your own solution later* ;-)

Comment: I will later. Have flaged it as duplicate and put the other question on top for now :)